# Folium Chloropleth not showing colors

Tags: csv, geojson, heatmap, folium

Geojson File: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sejal234/heatmaps_by/main/Zip_Codes.geojson

CSV: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sejal234/heatmaps_by/main/oyzipsattempt.csv (this is labelled new in my code)

I want to create a `chloroplet`h showing the number of OY (opportunity youth) per `zipcode` in Houston.

The following code:

```
  n = folium.Choropleth(
                 geo_data=r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sejal234/heatmaps_by/main/Zip_Codes.geojson',
                    data=new,
                    columns=['ZIPCODE','oy_count'], 
                    key_on='feature.properties.ZIP_CODE', 
                    fill_color='YlGn',
                    nan_fill_color="White", 
                    fill_opacity=1,
                    line_opacity=0.5,
                    legend_name='Num of OY', #title of the legend
                    highlight=True,
                    line_color='black')
        n.add_to(htx_map2) 
        folium.LayerControl().add_to(htx_map2)
        htx_map2
```

Should return a `chloropleth` on the yellow green scale, but instead returns the following (empty) map:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please change your code sample to fit [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as it's currently not reproducible and the error is likely to be somewhere else - result of your unmodified code after `new` and `htx_map2` are initialized:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGt4S.png

Comment: Has the issue in this question been resolved?